# jQuery.styledSelect plugin - opening the select from another element in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scope

I'm using this plugin - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/styledSelect to style a Select box on my page.  Demo page here - http://liepins.org/files/jQuery.styledSelect-1.0/examples.html

I've trying to figure out a way to open and close the select box from another element on the page, something like -

```
    $('#show-lists').styledSelect(); //apply the plugin on page load

    $("#another-button").toggle(
      function () {
         $('#show-lists').clickSelect() //open the dropdown
      },
      function () {
         $('#show-lists').closedSelect() //close it
      },
    );
```

The above code doesn't work, it's just there to illustrate. Any idea how I can access these methods externally? Or can anyone suggest an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the plugin to expose them as events bound to the control, e.g.

```
    closedSelect();
    s.change(closedSelect);
    currentZIndex -= 3;

    // New lines
    s.bind('openSelect', clickSelect);
    s.bind('closeSelect', closedSelect);
});
```

and then trigger the events from your code:

```
$("#another-button").toggle(
  function () {
     $('#show-lists').trigger('openSelect');
  },
  function () {
     $('#show-lists').trigger('closeSelect');
  },
);
```

although as you can see closedselect is already bound to the .change() event, so you could just call `$('#show-lists').change();` instead for the close case - but I think I'd stick to the separate event myself for clarity.

Comment: What is _"s"_ here? Is this `$('select')`?

Comment: @Manwal Yes, effectively. That's [the plugin's code](https://code.google.com/p/lnet/source/browse/trunk/jQuery.styledSelect/jQuery.styledSelect.js), line 100 onwards currently, plus two lines I proposed to expose its private functions by binding them to new events on the select box. You're right that they define `var s = jQuery(this);` within an each loop over the selects passed into the plugin.